# ConstraintValidator - Make JPA make the validation after input

Tags: java, validation, jpa, primefaces

Is it possible to make JPA validate an input right after a user types in anything?

I am using EclipseLink.

I dont want to wait for JPA to persist for the validation to kick in.

What I want to happen:

- I have a class
- I have multiple attributes
- Many attributes are gonna be input fields in the view
- I want to validate 2 (or more) attributes right after a user makes an input.

I am following this recipe: http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.no/2010/02/generic-class-level-constraint-for-bean.html

The problem is that the recipe stops before any validation happens.

Comment: A user "typing in something" has no bearing on JPA, since JPA is only involved when you pass an object to the JPA API! by persist/merge. You could make use of the BeanValidation API _yourself_ if that is your requirement

Comment: Do you need field level validation or class level (e.g. cross field), and @neilStockton: not true, field level is default in jsf... for the other one you need 'just' an existing utility framework

Comment: There is nothing in my comment that is "not true". I reply based on him wanting to use JPA for bean validation. What he uses for front-end is up to him and not the subject of the question

Comment: I need class validation (cross field). For example if you use @FacesValidator, and <f:validator> in the view, then it will validate on input. I want the same thing to happen on a class validator. Maybe with a ConstraintValidator

Comment: @Neil:What he uses in the front-end IS subject of the question although only visible in the tag, [tag:PrimeFaces] hence JSF. The OP clearly does not 'know' about the existence of BeanValidation, but you so (you mention it in the comment). So stating that the OP should call the BeanValidation api himself is sending down the wrong (unnecessarily complex) path...

Comment: Check http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateBean and see if it works for you (it should imo). In the mean time I'm trying to find a 'duplicate' question in StackOverflow